# Brewing a gruit. Myrica Gale alternative needed

Tags: ingredients, adjuncts, alternatives

I'm planning to brew my first gruit ale. I was planning to use Myrica Gale, Yarrow and Rosemary.

Sadly, I'm having serious difficulties with buying Myrica here in Europe.

Could anyone tell me a good alternative to Myrica Gale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Myricia Gale - Common names include Bog-myrtle and sweetgale.
Also be aware: The plant has been listed as an abortifacient and therefore should not be consumed by women who are, or might be, pregnant.

In the UK it is pretty easy to buy on e-bay:  http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/171997384055

I see from your profile/linkedIN you are may be in Spain, so take a look here: http://www.ebay.es/itm/181792919863?hash=item2a53b3d137:g:ZHYAAOSwLVZVmDF5

Comment: Thanks indeed. Both for the solution to the problem, and for consuming advice.

Comment: you're welcome :)